# FullCalendar getting incorrect dates

Tags: c#, jquery, fullcalendar

I am using FullCalendar v1.6.4 with jQuery v1.10.2

Basically, I am pulling the data for each event from an SQL Query. This particular event starts and ends on 10/10/2014. The date is correct all the way up until it actually renders on the calendar. The date is 10/10/2014 but it shows on the 11th.

Here is the code for the event:

```
events: [{
        title: 'Test Event',
        start: new Date(y, m, d - 6, 24, 0),
        end: new Date(y, m, d - 6, 16, 0),
        allDay: false,
        className: ["event", "bg-color-green"],
        id: 72
    }],
```

I made a **[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2cueru0f/)** as an example. The example shows the issue.

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: You're adding `24` hours to the date, so it's saying that the date is 12AM the next day.

Comment: @Ninsly I feel like an idiot. Thank you...

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you need.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var date = new Date();
  var d = date.getDate();
  var m = date.getMonth();
  var y = date.getFullYear();

  $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    editable: true,
    events: [{
      title: 'Test Event',
      start: new Date('2014-10-10T12:00:00'),
      end: new Date('2014-10-10T14:00:00'),
      allDay: false,
      className: ["event", "bg-color-green"],
      id: 72
    }],
  });

});
```

```css
.event {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
.bg-color-green {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://tutstub.com/fullcalendar.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://tutstub.com/jquery-ui.custom.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://tutstub.com/fullcalendar.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<div id='calendar'></div>
```

Comment: I havn't seen the comment while posting answer, but found that it is fixed , as mentioned in comment. However, i have made an effort to post this, so i kept this post, instead of deleting.